# Is it possible to emulate bind in Lua?

Tags: lua

Given a lua function with one argument, is it possible to bind this argument to a fixed value to obtain a function without arguments?

More generally, how do I bind certain input arguments of a lua function to certain values?

Comment: you mean currying (a function that returns a function)? It sure can be done, just return a function from your function. See [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CurriedLua).

Comment: It is not quite the same as currying since it does not require any changes to the function itself. Boost's bind is a good example of what I would like to accomplish: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/bind/bind.html#Purpose

Comment: @benno: And in what way does Boost.Bind *not* require changes to the function? It creates a *new* function object, which transforms the given arguments into a call to the old callable object. This effectively changes the function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in pretty much any language that have functions as first-class values.

```
function f1(a)
   return a+1
end

function bind(a)
   return function() return f1(a) end
end

local f2 = bind(42)
print(f2())
-- 43
```

This particular example works with specific function and number of arguments, but can easily be extended to take arbitrary function/arguments instead.

Comment: like function bind(f,...) local args={...} return function(...) return f(unpack(args),...) end end. This takes binds any number of arguments, and allows for adding extra arguments too. Like function add(a,b) return a+b end; add5=bind(add,5); print(add5(6))

Comment: @jpjacobs - `f(unpack(args),...)` uses only the first element of array `args`.  One need to build a new array as concatenation of two arrays `args` and `{...}` and only then `unpack` it.

Answer (score 0):

I just made an helper function to do what Boost::bind does :

- It handles placeholder to be able to replace any positional argument
- It handles nil anywhere

## Usage :

`function_binder(base_function, placeholders_format, args...)`

- base_function (function) : The function to wrap
- placeholders_format (string) : represent how the args should be placed, each character represent an argument

  - `.` : represent an argument from the wrapper
  - `A` : represent an argument from the binder
  - `~` : represent all pending arguments from the wrapper

See following example for better understanding.

### Simple example:

```
local function divide(a, b)
    return a / b
end

local div_by_4 = function_binder(divide, ".A", 4)
print(div_by_4(12)) -- => prints: 3

local div_12_by = function_binder(divide, "A.", 12)
print(div_12_by(4)) -- => prints: 3
```

### You can also use builtin function:

```
local debug_print = function_binder(print, "A~", "DEBUG:")
debug_print("some logs for debug")
-- => prints: DEBUG some logs for debug

-- '~' will put all following arguments:
debug_print("some", "logs", "for", "debug")
-- => prints: DEBUG some logs for debug
```

### You can make complex stuff too:

```
local function stuff(...)
    print("Args: ", ...)
end

local wrapper = function_binder(stuff, ".A..AA~", "two", "five", "six")
wrapper(1, 3, 4, 7, nil, 9)
-- => prints: 1 two 3 4 five six 7 nil 9
```

## Object Oriented way

### Setup

To do more OO stuff, you can use the debug library:

```
-- apply metatable to all function
debug.setmetatable(function()end, {
    __index = {
        bind = function_binder,
    },
})
```

### Usage

```
local debug_print = print:bind("A~", "DEBUG:")
debug_print("add some log")
-- => prints: DEBUG: add some log
```

## Here is the function_binder code :

```
local function packed_args_append(packed, nb_insert, ...)
    nb_insert = nb_insert > 0 and nb_insert or select('#', ...)

    for i = 1, nb_insert do
        packed[packed.n + 1] = select(i, ...)
        packed.n = packed.n + 1
    end
end

-- replace table.unpack as it doesn't always handle nil values correctly..
local function unpacknil(packed)
    local nb_args = packed.n

    local function unpack_n(n)
        if n == nb_args then
            return packed[n]
        end
        return packed[n], unpack_n(n + 1)
    end
    return unpack_n(1)
end

function function_binder(self, placeholder_format, ...)
    local placeholders = table.pack(...)

    return function(...)
        local args = {n = 0}
        local arg_idx = 1
        local placeholder_idx = 1


        for c in placeholder_format:gmatch"." do
            if c == 'A' then
                packed_args_append(args, 1, placeholders[placeholder_idx])
                placeholder_idx = placeholder_idx + 1
            elseif c == '.' then
                packed_args_append(args, 1, select(arg_idx, ...))
                arg_idx = arg_idx + 1
            elseif c == '~' then
                packed_args_append(args, -1, select(arg_idx, ...))
                break
            end
        end
        --return self(table.unpack(args))
        return self(unpacknil(args))
    end
end
```

It works perfectly with Lua 5.3

Hosted here : https://github.com/Bew78LesellB/luaMiscTests/commit/e9e52aea7933b58332fff36738356f18aed3db92