# Call Lua function by reference

Tags: function, lua

OK, I searched for this, but to no avail. It's kind of a vague thought/idea so... here goes.

Is it possible, in Lua, to call a function (with declared values) and then call it again by reference (without having to pass the values again)?

What I am trying to do is create a larger generic function (that is used repeatedly) that has the passed values declared when the generic function is called.

If the generic function fails, I want it to recycle and try to call itself with the same used values (without having to pass them to the function again.)

If I didn't lose anyone, hopefully there are a few thoughts & ideas out there.
Tim

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to emulate bind in Lua?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117440/is-it-possible-to-emulate-bind-in-lua)

Answer (score 4):

If you want arguments passed to a function, you need to pass them, every time.

You could bind some arguments to a function via a closure:

```
function bind(f, ...)
    local args = {...}
    return function()
        return f(unpack(args))
    end
end

foo = bind(print, "This", "is", "a", "test")
foo() --> This    is      a       test
foo() --> This    is      a       test
```

Would be a lot easier to answer your question if you posted some example code.

Comment: Mud, I think you figured out what I was trying to do. I was just reading on closure and might have a gander down the "bind"ing road... I would have liked to be more specific, but as I said, this is just in the initial vague thought/idea stage. Thx

Comment: Is there a way that this can be done if the values being passed are variables and not actual string values?<br/><br/>I am trying to send variables to a function and if the variables' values change at a later time, calling the original (in this case "foo()" will return "This is a test" and not the new values of the variables...<br/>Thx, Tim

Comment: Yes, you can bind to variables, but the closure will be bound to the local variables in `bind`, not to the caller's variables. Lua variables hold references to objects. They cannot hold references to variables. If all your functions took a `table` of arguments, you could bind to a mutable value and change its contents later.  **Side note:** We could probably come up with a very elegant solution to your problem, if you told us what the actual problem is.

Comment: Mud, what I am envisioning, is downloading and using LuaZip to unzip an archive. When the function is originally called, the source, destination, password, etc are all provided. If the download or unzip action fails, I want it to retry the download/unzip function without needing to re-send all the variables.

Comment: Is the download asynchronous?

Comment: Ya, I want to download the whole package and then work with it.

Comment: Thinking about this overnight, I should be able achieve what I want by creating a table with the variable values and sending this to the function. One of the variable values will be the name of the table itself, so if the function needs to recycle, it can call the table (the table name being one of the stored variable values)...